Setting the shortcut of MacOS Mission Control with Applescript
I am used to displaying MacOS Mission Control windows with a middle click (mouse 3) but MacOS Sequoia 15.1 and 15.2 do not save the Mission Control display setting with the mouse "Desktop and Dock > Mission Control > Shortcuts". At each startup, the setting is lost and reverts to its default value.
I asked for a workaround using shell command default write here but no one seems to have an answer :
Setting the shortcut of MacOS Mission Control with default write shell command?
Is there a way to do that with full Applescript?
At this time, I can just get the dialog window "Shortcuts" to open :
set paneID to "com.apple.Desktop-Settings.extension"
tell application "System Settings"
    activate
    delay 0.7
    set the current pane to pane id paneID
    delay 0.7
    reveal anchor "Shortcuts" of pane id paneID
    delay 0.7
    
end tell

I don't know how to modify the second popup menu (mouse shortcut).

Here's what I did: it's a bit messy and could probably be optimized, but it works for me.
use AppleScript version "2.4" -- Yosemite (10.10) or later
use scripting additions

----------------------------------------------------------------------
set paneID to "com.apple.Desktop-Settings.extension"
set dlogTitle to "Raccourcis Mission Control"
set popupMenuName to "Raccourci souris" -- ///// localization
set popupMenuItem to " Bouton de souris 3" -- ///// localization

----------------------------------------------------------------------
tell application "System Settings"
    ------------------------ open System Settings/Bureau et Dock
    activate
    delay 0.7
    set the current pane to pane id paneID
    delay 0.7
    ------------------------ open panneau "Raccourcis"
    reveal anchor "Shortcuts" of pane id paneID
    delay 0.7
    ------------------------ click menu local
    try
        tell application "System Events"
            tell pop up button popupMenuName of group 1 of scroll area 1 of group 1 of sheet 1 of window 1 of application process "System Settings"
                click
                delay 0.2
                click menu item popupMenuItem of menu 1
            end tell
            delay 0.5
            
            ------------------------ close panneau
            click button 1 of group 1 of sheet 1 of window 1 of application process "System Settings"
            delay 0.8
            ------------------------ close System Settings
            tell application "System Settings" to quit
        end tell
    on error errMsg number errNum
        display dialog errMsg as text buttons {"Annuler"} default button 1 with title dlogTitle with icon 0
    end try
end tell

